# VueJS Router-link not linking to the view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a problem with the router link. When I put it in a view, it works very well, I have a clickable link. But when I put a router link in a component, built into a view, then the router link no longer works: I would like "just" to link to the detail of a project.

This work (`resources/js/views/HomepageView.vue`)

```
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'projects.show', params: { slug: slideshowProject.slug }}">
    <a href="#" class="btn-secondary">See
        Campaign</a>
</router-link>
```

This doesn't work (`resources/js/components/UserProject.vue`)

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'projects.show', params: { slug: project.slug }}">
    <h4>{‌{ project.title}}</h4>
</router-link>
```

Script part of the page :

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "user-projects",
        data() {
            return {
                projects: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getUserProject()
        },

        methods: {
            getUserProject() {
                this.$store.dispatch('getUserProjects', {
                    limit: 2
                }).then(response => {
                    this.projects = response.data.data;
                })
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

My router.js

```
import Homepage from '../views/frontend/HomepageView';
import ProjectDetails from '../views/frontend/ProjectDetailsView';
import LoginView from '../views/frontend/LoginView';
import RegisterView from '../views/frontend/RegisterView';
import DashboardIndexView from '../views/dashboard/DashboardIndexView';

export const routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        name: 'homepage',
        component: Homepage
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'frontend-login',
        component: LoginView
    },
    {
        path: '/projects/:slug',
        name: 'projects.show',
        component: ProjectDetails
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        name: 'frontend-register',
        component: RegisterView
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard-index',
        component: DashboardIndexView
    }
];
```

I don't understand where is my mistake :/

Comment: Can you post how you initialize the data on these Vue instances?

Comment: Sure ! I've just edited my post :)

Comment: Is `UserProject` a child component of `HomepageView`? We will actually need to see your router configs as well.

Comment: UserProject is a child component of DashboardIndexView.vue . I have a view, called DashboardIndexView, and inside of it, i have a component "UserProject". I've added the route.js part

Comment: [This post](/a/42604186/3634538) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jom, the problem was that my "slug" was empty, and indeed when i look at the console, the warning was there.

```
[vue-router] missing param for named route "projects.show": Expected "slug" to be defined
```

Comment: You should accept his answer to help others find correct solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can check slug is not empty before render a router link, like below sample:

```
<router-link v-if="project.slug" to="{ name: 'projects.show', params: { slug: project.slug }}">
    <h4>{‌{ project.title}}</h4>
</router-link>
```

But I am sure, why slug is empty.